# Killing a process in debian - "sh: /usr/bin/p$: not found"

Tags: debian

I just logged into my server via shell as I am being denied access via ssh. There seems to be a process thats continuously running and is producing the following -

```
sh: /usr/bin/p$: not found
sh: /usr/bin/p$: not found
sh: /usr/bin/p$: not found
sh: /usr/bin/p$: not found
```

Any ideas as to how I can stop this?

Comment: Looks like a buggy Bash script is running. Do 'ps awx' and see if there are any likely culprits, such as 'some_script.sh'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also do a brute-force search for a script containing `/usr/bin/p$` with something like:

```
find /*bin/ /usr/*bin/ /usr/local/*bin/ /etc/cron.*/ /etc/init.d/ -type f -exec egrep -l '^\/usr\/bin\/p\$' \{\} \;
```

and - if that fails - something even more brutish:

```
find / -type f -exec egrep -l '^\/usr\/bin\/p\$' \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

pstree and the more verbose "pstree -cpa" give a pretty good snapshot of the child process relationships across the system.

It is difficult to catch short lived processes, but if you do catch it the pstree will show what is starting the process in question.

sample pstree output:

```
pstree
init─┬─acpid
     ├─atd
     ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
     ├─bluetoothd
     ├─bonobo-activati───2*[{bonobo-activat}]
     ├─chrome─┬─chrome───{chrome}
     │        ├─chrome
     │        └─21*[{chrome}]
     ├─chrome─┬─2*[chrome───4*[{chrome}]]
     │        └─nacl_helper_boo
     ├─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-da}]
     ├─cron
     ├─cupsd
     ├─2*[dbus-daemon]
     ├─dbus-launch
     ├─dhclient
     ├─dnsmasq
     ├─gconfd-2
     ├─gdm-binary─┬─gdm-simple-slav─┬─Xorg
     │            │                 ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gnome-session─┬─applet.+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─bluetoo+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─gdu-not+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-p+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-p+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─metacit+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─mintupd+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─nautilu+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─polkit-+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─ssh-age+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─wicd-cl+
     │            │                 │                 │               ├─zeitgei+
     │            │                 │                 │               └─2*[{gno+
     │            │                 │                 └─{gdm-session-wo}
     │            │                 └─{gdm-simple-sla}
     │            └─{gdm-binary}
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─gnome-keyring-d───5*[{gnome-keyring-}]
     ├─gnome-screensav───{gnome-screensa}
     ├─gnome-settings-───{gnome-settings}
     ├─gvfs-afc-volume───{gvfs-afc-volum}
     ├─gvfs-fuse-daemo───3*[{gvfs-fuse-daem}]
     ├─gvfs-gdu-volume
     ├─gvfs-gphoto2-vo
     ├─gvfsd
     ├─gvfsd-burn
     ├─gvfsd-metadata
     ├─gvfsd-trash
     ├─indicator-apple───2*[{indicator-appl}]
     ├─indicator-appli───{indicator-appl}
     ├─indicator-sound───2*[{indicator-soun}]
     ├─irqbalance
     ├─libvirtd───6*[{libvirtd}]
     ├─mintmenu─┬─gnome-terminal─┬─bash───pstree
     │          │                ├─gnome-pty-helpe
     │          │                └─2*[{gnome-terminal}]
     │          └─2*[{mintmenu}]
     ├─named───4*[{named}]
     ├─nmbd
     ├─notify-osd───{notify-osd}
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─pulseaudio─┬─gconf-helper───{gconf-helper}
     │            └─2*[{pulseaudio}]
     ├─rsyslogd───2*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
     ├─smbd───smbd
     ├─syndaemon
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     ├─udisks-daemon─┬─udisks-daemon
     │               └─2*[{udisks-daemon}]
     ├─upowerd───{upowerd}
     ├─upstart-socket-
     ├─upstart-udev-br
     ├─wicd───wicd-monitor
     ├─wnck-applet───{wnck-applet}
     ├─wpa_supplicant
     └─zeitgeist-daemo─┬─cat
                       ├─zeitgeist-datah
                       └─{zeitgeist-daem}
```

adding the options -cpa

pstree -cpa

changes the display by giving details of each process, the process number for killing and any options specified when starting the process

Answer (score 0):

**Use killall**

To kill a proccess you can use:
`kill <PID>`
OR
`killall <Process Name>`

You can find the pid on the left by doing `ps -aux`

:) --- Olivr3000